# composition of permutations example

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, group-homomorphism

In *Algebra* by Artin, there is an example (2.5.13), where he defines a homomorphism from $S_4$ to $S_3$.

> there are three ways to partition the set of four indices {${1, 2, 3, 4}$} into pairs of subsets of order two, namely
>
> $y_1: \{1, 2\} \cup \{3, 4\}$,
>
> $y_2: \{1, 3\}\cup \{2, 4\}$,
>
> $y_3: \{1, 4\} \cup\{2, 3\}$.
>
> An element of the symmetric group $S_4$ permutes the four indices, and by doing so it also permutes these three partitions. This defines the map $f$ from $S_4$ to the group of
>   permutations
>   of the set $\{y_1, y_2, y_3\}$, which is the symmetric group $S_3$.
>
> For example,the 4-cycle $p = (1\,2\,3\,4)$ acts on subsets of order two as follows:
>
> {1, 2}     $\rightarrow$ {2, 3}
>
> {1, 3} $\rightarrow$ {2, 4}
>
> {1, 4} $\rightarrow$ {1, 2}
>
> {2, 3}$\rightarrow$ {3, 4}
>
> {2, 4} $\rightarrow$ {1, 3}
>
> {3, 4}$\rightarrow$ {1, 4}.

My  question is how do you work with these operations? and how do you permute them?

For example, Artin writes that $(1,2)(3,4)$ is in the Kernel. So this means that $(1,2)(3,4)$  maps to the identity. Does that mean it maps to {1,2,3,4}? (weren't we mapping to $S_3$?) Would this map $y_1$ to $y_3$ ? How do I calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(12)(34)$ is in the kernel of the defined mapping because it takes $y_i\to y_i\,,i=1,2,3$.  For instance,  since $y_1=\{1,2\}\cup\{3,4\}$, and $(12)(34)$ takes $\{1,2\}\to \{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}\to\{3,4\}$, it takes $y_1$ to $y_1$.

If we look at $y_2$, we see that $\{1,3\}\to\{2,4\}$ and $\{2,4\}\to\{1,3\}$.  Thus $(12)(34)$ takes $y_2$ to $y_2$.

Similarly for $y_3$.

So, $(12)(34)\to e\in S_3$ under the mapping.

As far as working with them, consider $(1234)$.  From your calculations, we get $y_1\to y_3$. And $y_2\to y_2$.  And finally $y_3\to y_1$. Thus, under the mapping Artin has defined, we get $(1234)\in S_4\to (13)\in S_3$.

Comment: I'm confused with the notation. Is (1,2)  the operation where we map 1 to 2 and 2 to 1? Or does (1,2)(3,4) means 1 maps to 3, 2 maps to 4?

Comment: $(12)$ swaps $1$ and $2$.  $(12)(34)$ swaps $1$ and $2$ and swaps $3$ and $4$.

Comment: So [1,2} and {2,1} are the same? (order doesn't matter?)

Comment: Write the transposition with parentheses.   $(12)=(21)$.  Just to remind you:   the $n$-cycle works as follows.   $(abcdefg)$ means $a\to b\to c\to d\to e\to f\to g\to a$.